# Unable to call the GetMsgPrc using the WH_GETMESSAGE hook

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

I am trying to print a message inside the hook procedure GetMsgProc as mentioned in the code below:

```
LRESULT WINAPI GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    printf("inside hook proc");

    return CallNextHookEx(getmsghook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}


void main()
{
    HINSTANCE hins;
    hins = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    getmsghook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, (HOOKPROC) GetMsgProc, hins, 0);

    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    UnhookWindowsHookEx(getmsghook);
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------------------

My guess is that, for every keyboard or mouse input, that message should get printed. But I am unable to figure out why that's not happening. Could you please help.

Comment: If I recall correctly, that hook only captures messages that are _sent_ to a window handle.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Not necessarily. If I replace WH_GETMESSSAGE with WH_MOUSE_LL, it works.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError. `WH_GETMESSAGE` catches any message that passes through `(Peek|Get)Message()`, whether it is posted, sent, broadcasted, etc.  You might be thinking of `WH_CALLWNDPROC/RET` instead, which catches any message that is dispatched to a window.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: This is a little out of context from the above mentioned question. Does WH_CALLWNDPROC hook on to Touch events happening inside internet explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global hooks must be implemented in a .DLL, the only exceptions are the low-kevel keyboard and mouse hooks. Check the return value of `SetWindowsHookEx`, it is probably NULL.